# Laravel not finding the master view after having validation errors

Tags: php, laravel, validation, view

I have ran into a weird problem with Laravel. I have a system to create and edit PDFs in Laravel. I noticed that whenever there's a validation error with the information provided to edit the PDF, Laravel doesn't find the extended `master` view that contains the `edit` view. Sometimes it shows an HTTP 500 Internal Server error, sometimes it displays the `edit` view without any styling (given that the stylesheets are in the `master` view). Everything works fine in the `create` view, but not the in the `edit` view.

Why could be causing this problem? Everything is the same in both views:

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('panel.layouts.master', ['viewType' => 'page', 'viewId' => 'quotes-create'])
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('panel.layouts.master', ['viewType' => 'page', 'viewId' => 'quotes-edit'])
```

*Important Note:*

This only happens when there are validation errors, not when entering the Edit route for the first time.

I am using Laravel 5.6

Comment: What's the full error message that you're getting when you get the 500?

Comment: That's the only error I get. It tells me that the page is currently unable to handle the request. So I am guessing it's because Laravel sends the `edit` view that extends the `master` view, and it is unable to find it

Comment: Check your Laravel error logs in `/storage/logs`. There should be more information there. I'm guessing that it's finding the view just fine, but something else is throwing an error, such as a missing variable.

Comment: Thanks! I now know that the problem is. It gives me 

`local.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65028096 bytes)`

I guess it's because of the big amount of information that I am passing between views. The PDFs require a lot of images and data.